# Problem:Jstree select node always returns the container node

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm new to JQuery/Jstree. When I'm trying to select a node programmatically, it always returns the container node, instead of the child node I was trying to get.
Please help.

My code is as follows,

```
<div id="containerId" class="demo">
<ul>
    <li id="phtml_1">
        <a href="#">Root node 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="zzx">
                <a href="#">Child node 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="phtml_3">
                <a href="#">Child node 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***javascript***

```
$(function () {
    $("#containerId").jstree({ 
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "ui" ]
    });
});
```

***script***

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var node= $("#containerId").jstree("select_node","#zzx"); 
  //Problem here, why the id is still the "containerId", not the "zzx"?
  alert(node.attr("id"));
});
```

thanks --Roger

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `node` to be equal to `#('containerId')` and nothing else.  When you call a method on an object in jQuery, the result is just the object.  That way, you can chain methods like this:

```
$('#containerId').method1().method2().method3();
```

If you want to programmatically select a node, you have already done that correctly:

```
$("#containerId").jstree("select_node","#zzx");
```

Since you know the node you just selected, you can get the node just like any other element with jQuery:

```
$('#zzx')
```

If instead you are trying to call function every time a node is selected, use this:

```
$('#containerId').bind('select_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
    alert(data.rslt.obj.attr('id'));
})
```